# How do you "abort" a method in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ibaction, abort

I know there are ways around this, but I would like to know if the following question is possible. Can you "abort" a method in Objective-C? In this case it is on Cocoa Touch. I have an IBAction. In that action I have in if/else if/else statement. If it is else, I would like to abort the rest of the method. Kind of like return 0, but for an IBAction.

Is this possible? If so, how would you accomplish this. The entire method is kind of long, but here is the part I am looking at:

```
if ([unitType isEqualToString:@"mg/dl"])
    {
        //Unit is mg.
        typeOfUnit = unitType;
    }
    else if ([unitType isEqualToString:@"mmol"])
    {
        //Unit is mmol
        typeOfUnit = unitType;
    }
    else
    {
        //Apparently either a bug or a (null) item.
        typeOfUnit = @"mg/dl";
        [[LEItemStore sharedStore] createItem];
        item = [[[LEItemStore sharedStore] allItems] objectAtIndex:0];
        [self loadItems:self];

        //Code to Abort the rest of the method here.
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: a 'return'? .....

Comment: @MitchWheat, . . . Okay... Fail. Duh. I'm going to hate myself forever. Thanks. Post that as an answer.

Comment: yah. hes correct. You should use return.

Comment: @AceLegend :D -- well there are worse questions on SO

Comment: Now to wait for the 17 answers about `return` to roll in.

Comment: I'm voting to close. This was just a huge over sight.

Comment: @Daij-Djan, Well, thanks I feel a lot better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's simple:

`return;`

(So simple, that it's too short to post without this sentence.)